# email integration along with struts

Tags: java, email, jsp, struts, freemarker

Is there anything similar to freemarker that can be used along with struts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Tiles + Velocity :-)

http://tiles.apache.org/

http://velocity.apache.org/